# Uncaught TypeError with Javascript and Openlayers

Tags: javascript

I have some issues with a Javascript and OpenLayers.

My code looks likes this at the moment:

```
   <!-- OpenLayers Example  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <!-- Styles for example -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://playground.fmeserver.com/css/FMEServerExamples.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Include FMEServer.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.fmeserver.com/js/v3/FMEServer.js"></script>
    <!-- The following are Required for OpenLayers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <!--Open Layers-->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map { 
        width: 1500px;
        height: 800px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>This example clips data to a user drawn polygon.</h4>
    <form id="exampleForm">
        <label><b>Step 1</b> - Draw the Polygon (Double Click to Close): </label>
        <input id="draw" type="button" value="Draw" />
        <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" /><br />
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>

        <label><b>Step 2</b> - Submit the Request to FME Server: </label>
        <input type="button" onclick="processClip();" value="Clip Data To Area" />
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var drawControl, mouseControl, polygonLayer, map;
        var clippingGeometry = [];

    window.onload = function() {

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.974044, 57.708682]),
          zoom: 12
        })
      });

      // Lager från Geoserver
        var Geoserver_WMS = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: "Test Geoserver",
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: '*URLGoesHere*',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': '*LayerGoesHere*', 'TILED': true,
                    'STYLES': ''
                },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3007'),
            })
        });

        map.addLayer(Geoserver_WMS);

        document.getElementById( "draw" ).setAttribute( "onclick", "drawPolygon();" );
        document.getElementById( "reset" ).setAttribute( "onclick", "drawReset();" );

        FMEServer.init({
            server : "https://demos-safe-software.fmecloud.com",
            token : "568c604bc1f235bbe137c514e7c61a8436043070"

        });
    };

        function drawPolygon() {
            drawReset();

            polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Polygon Layer" );
            mouseControl = new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition();

            map.addLayer( polygonLayer );
            map.addControl( mouseControl );

            drawControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature( polygonLayer,
                OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon );
            map.addControl( drawControl );
            drawControl.activate();
        }

        function drawReset() {
            if( drawControl ) {
                map.removeLayer( polygonLayer );
                polygonLayer = null;
                mouseControl.deactivate();
                mouseControl = null;
                drawControl.deactivate();
                drawControl = null;
                clippingGeometry = [];
            }
        }

        function extractShape() {
            if( polygonLayer.features[0] ) {
                var vertices = polygonLayer.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
                for( var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++ ) {
                    var point = vertices[i].transform( toProjection, fromProjection );
                    clippingGeometry.push( [ point.x, point.y ] );
                }
                clippingGeometry.push( clippingGeometry[0] );
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function showResults( json ) {
            // The following is to write out the full return object
            // for visualization of the example
            var hr = document.createElement( "hr" );
            var div = document.createElement( "div" );

            // This extracts the download link to the clipped data
            var download = json.serviceResponse.url;

            div.innerHTML = "<h4>Return Object:</h4><pre>"+JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4)+"</pre>";
            div.innerHTML += "<hr><a href=\""+download+"\">Download Result</a>";
            document.body.appendChild( hr );
            document.body.appendChild( div );
        }

        function processClip() {
            var repository = "REST-Playground";
            var workspace = "WKTClip.fmw";

            if( extractShape() ) {

                // Process the clippingGeometry into a WKT Polygon string
                var geometry = "POLYGON((";

                for( var i = 0; i < clippingGeometry.length; i++ ) {
                    var lat = clippingGeometry[i][1];
                    var lng = clippingGeometry[i][0];
                    geometry += lng+" "+lat+",";
                }

                // Remove trailing , from string
                geometry = geometry.substr( 0, geometry.length - 1 );
                geometry += "))";

                // Set the parameters for the Data Download Service (ESRI Shapefile Format)
                // FORMAT OPTIONS: ACAD, SHAPE, GML, OGCKML
                var params = "GEOM="+geometry+"&FORMAT=SHAPE";

                // Use the FME Server Data Download Service
                FMEServer.runDataDownload( repository, workspace, params, showResults );
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit "Draw" i get the following Error-message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined

I´m supposed to get coordinates and be able to draw a polygon. But it won´t work.

Can anyone see whats wrong in the code? I just can't figure it out, and it drives me crazy.
Very thankfull for any suggestions.

Comment: `var map = new ol.Map({...` remove the `var`

Comment: You have 2 variables called `map` in different scopes. Perhaps if you sort that out...

Answer (score 0):

You have a globally scope map variable and a local scoped one, with your code the was it is, you're never setting the globally scoped variable to a value so it's always `undefined`. Hence the error message

Change the code here

```
window.onload = function() {

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.974044, 57.708682]),
          zoom: 12
        })
      });
```

And remove the `var`

```
window.onload = function() {

      map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.974044, 57.708682]),
          zoom: 12
        })
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the awnser Geroge. I removed the var but get another error messege in the events.js:

"Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function"

Any suggestions?